# ¿Como usar por ejemplo este metodo public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context) en otra clase?

Tags: java, android

En una clase estoy validando la conexión a la red en Android, y quisiera validar si el valor true de ese método en otra clase se ejecute otro método.

Clase 1

```
public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context) {
    return true;
}
```

Clase 2

```
public void saveLocation(Context ctx){
    //Codigo ejecución si hay conexión.
}
```

Comment: ¿Buscas algo como `if (Clase1.isConnectedWifi(ctx)) { ... }`?

Comment: Si validando con un if seria perfecto, desde la clase 2 tienes un ejemplo de la sintaxis ?

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Tu pregunta es si existe una `Clase1` con ese método?

Comment: Mira si public void saveLocation(Context ctx){
    //Codigo ejecución si isConnectedWifi es true
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo, donde usas el contexto para llamar el método `isConnectedWifi()` el cual retorna un valor boleano, con esto puedes determinar si ejecutas o no tu otro método :

```
public void saveLocation(Context ctx){
   if(isConnectedWifi(ctx)){ 
    //Conectado ejecuta el método.
    }else{
    //NO Conectado.
   }    
}
```